# Python: Iterating through the columns in a list of list to find the palindromes

Tags: python, list, palindrome

Here I have a word list as:

```
[['r', 'o', 't', 'o', 'r'], ['e', 'v', 'e', 'i', 'a'], ['f', 'i', 'n', 'e', 'd'], ['e', 'n', 'e', 't', 'a'], ['r', 'a', 't', 'e', 'r']]
```

And I have to display all the palindromes in this list which are in rows as well as columns.
I have coded to find all the palindromes in the rows. But cannot implement a method to find the palindromes in the columns.

Here is my code so far:

```
result_1=""
if len(palindrome)==len_line_str:
    for row in range(len(palindrome)):
        for horizontal_line in range(len(palindrome[row])):
            if ''.join(palindrome[row])==''.join(reversed(palindrome[row])):
                result_1=''.join(palindrome[row])+" is a palindrome starting at ["+str(row)+"]["+str(row)+"] and is a row in the table"
    print(result_1)
```

Which will display the output:

```
rotor is a palindrome starting at [0][0] and is a row in the table
```

Where "rotor" is a palindrome.

I need a method to get the palindromes in the columns which are:
"refer", "tenet", "radar"

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: eye, let me know if you don't understand something of my answer, good luck!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) to transpose your lists:

```
>>> t = [['r', 'o', 't', 'o', 'r'], ['e', 'v', 'e', 'i', 'a'], ['f', 'i', 'n', 'e', 'd'], ['e', 'n', 'e', 't', 'a'], ['r', 'a', 't', 'e', 'r']]
[['r', 'o', 't', 'o', 'r'], ['e', 'v', 'e', 'i', 'a'], ['f', 'i', 'n', 'e', 'd'], ['e', 'n', 'e', 't', 'a'], ['r', 'a', 't', 'e', 'r']]
>>> list(zip(*t))
[('r', 'e', 'f', 'e', 'r'), ('o', 'v', 'i', 'n', 'a'), ('t', 'e', 'n', 'e', 't'), ('o', 'i', 'e', 't', 'e'), ('r', 'a', 'd', 'a', 'r')]
```

Your columns are now rows, and you can apply the same method than before. If you just need the words, you can use list comprehensions:

```
>>> rows = [['r', 'o', 't', 'o', 'r'], ['e', 'v', 'e', 'i', 'a'], ['f', 'i', 'n', 'e', 'd'], ['e', 'n', 'e', 't', 'a'], ['r', 'a', 't', 'e', 'r']]
>>> [''.join(row) for row in rows if row[::-1] == row ]
['rotor']
>>> [''.join(column) for column in zip(*rows) if column[::-1] == column ]
['refer', 'tenet', 'radar']
```

Comment: Is there any other way without using 'zip' because I'm trying to code with the basics, as I'm a beginner to Python. @Eric

Comment: @eye [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) is a built-in function in Python, I would say it belongs to the "basics"

Comment: Eric, just brilliant, very clean solution! its a plus one!

Answer (score 2):

This will do the job:

```
palindrome=[['r', 'o', 't', 'o', 'r'], ['e', 'v', 'e', 'i', 'a'], ['f', 'i', 'n', 'e', 'd'], ['e', 'n', 'e', 't', 'a'], ['r', 'a', 't', 'e', 'r']]
n=len(palindrome)
for col in range(len(palindrome[0])):
    col_word=[palindrome[i][col] for i in range(n)]
    if ''.join(col_word)==''.join(reversed(col_word)):
        result=''.join(col_word)+" is a palindrome starting at ["+str(col)+"] and is a col in the table"
        print(result)
```

This prints

```
refer is a palindrome starting at [0] and is a col in the table
tenet is a palindrome starting at [2] and is a col in the table
radar is a palindrome starting at [4] and is a col in the table
```

Basically, in order to access the words in the column, you can do

```
col_word=[palindrome[i][col] for i in range(n)]
```

This fixes the column and iterates over the rows. The rest of the code is structures similarly to yours.

​

Comment: That's great Miriam! I didn't think in that, it's a plus one, you can check my answer to see another alternative if you like :)

Answer (score 1):

I saw you did not want to use Zip (which I would recommend using):

## Alternative answer:

```
list_ = [['r', 'o', 't', 'o', 'r'], ['e', 'v', 'e', 'i', 'a'], ['f', 'i', 'n', 'e', 'd'], ['e', 'n', 'e', 't', 'a'], ['r', 'a', 't', 'e', 'r']]
```

You can get the palindromes (rows) by checking each list with the reversed list [::-1]:

```
[i==i[::-1] for i in list_]
# prints [True, False, False, False, False]
```

And get the palindromes (columns) by 1. create the column list  (called list_2 below) with a list comprehension and 2. same principle as above:

```
list_2 = [[i[ind] for i in list_] for ind in range(len(list_))]
[i==i[::-1] for i in list_2]
# prints [True, False, True, False, True]
```

### Update

If you want the answers directly you can do:

```
[i for i in list_ if i==i[::-1]] 
# prints [['r', 'o', 't', 'o', 'r']]
# and list_2: [['r', 'e', 'f', 'e', 'r'],['t', 'e', 'n', 'e', 't'],['r', 'a', 'd', 'a', 'r']]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do it. **I will take as example your code because of your effort on it**

Another alternative following your code, is creating the columns in another list and check wich of them are palindromes:

```
palindrome = [['r', 'o', 't', 'o', 'r'], 
              ['e', 'v', 'e', 'i', 'a'], 
              ['f', 'i', 'n', 'e', 'd'], 
              ['e', 'n', 'e', 't', 'a'], 
              ['r', 'a', 't', 'e', 'r']]

len_line_str = 5

result_1=""

def is_pal(string):
  return string == reversed(string)

colums = []
if len(palindrome)==len_line_str:
  for row in range(len(palindrome)):
    vertical = []
    if ''.join(palindrome[row])==''.join(reversed(palindrome[row])):
      result_1+=''.join(palindrome[row])+" is a palindrome starting at ["+str(0)+"]["+str(row)+"] and is a row in the table. " + "\n"
    for horizontal_line in range(len(palindrome[row])):
      if(len_line_str-1 > horizontal_line): 
        vertical += [palindrome[horizontal_line][row]]
      else:
        vertical += [palindrome[horizontal_line][row]]
        colums += [(vertical,row)]

  for word in colums:
    if ''.join(word[0])==''.join(reversed(word[0])):
        result_1+=''.join(word[0])+" is a palindrome starting at ["+str(0)+"]["+str(word[1])+"] and is a column in the table" + "\n"
  print(result_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. First loop iterates through the list s and the second loop iterates through each list.

Assuming s is the name of the list- [['r', 'o', 't', 'o', 'r'], ['e', 'v', 'e', 'i', 'a'], ['f', 'i', 'n', 'e', 'd'], ['e', 'n', 'e', 't', 'a'], ['r', 'a', 't', 'e', 'r']]

```js
for i in xrange(0,len(s),1):
    str = ""
    for j in s:
        str = str + j[i]
    print str
    if str == str[::-1]:
        print str," is a pallindrome - column", i
    else:
        print str," is not a pallindrome - column", i
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no column wise traversal in Python. One hacky way you can follow is to perform transpose operation on your input matrix. Below is a simple way to implement transpose using list comprehensions.

```
def transpose(matrix):
    if not matrix:
        return []
    return [[row[i] for row in matrix] for i in range(len(matrix[0]))]
```

Your same logic should work once modify your input using transpose.

Hope this helps!!